# Accessing PKCS12 stored certificate

Tags: cryptoapi, pkcs#12, mscapi

I'm exploring a case where the stored certificate must be extracted for using with OpenSSL's (C++ application). It is imported to Local Computer\Personal store, and had contained a password-protected private key.

What will be available to me via MS CryptoAPI?

What I want to is to either retrieve the original certificate, or its private key in either password-protected or unprotected form. Is it possible? Or CryptoAPI isn't intended for providing certificate copies and I shall use its functions instead of using OpenSSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What I want to is to either retrieve the original certificate, or its private key in either password-protected or unprotected form. Is it possible?**

Yes, you can export your PFX from certificate store using cryptoAPI with  [`PFXExportCertStore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387311%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)